# Laravel shared hosting htaccess trailing slashes redirect problem

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

I have public folder in my project folder and added the .htaccess file in the project folder.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now public is removed from url and everything works fine except one that when I hit a url with a trailing slash it redirects to /public/...